# What's the correct result of boost::lexical_cast and std::to_string for unsigned char

Tags: c++, c++11

What's the correct result of below cast from char to string?

I heard that old boost version **1.46** lexical_cast output was **56**, I don't have that version near me that I can't test it. But
**boost library(1.49) output is: 8**

```
  unsigned char c= 56;
  std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(c);
  std::cout << "boost::lexical_cast: " << s << std::endl;
```

**C++11 to_string output is: 56**

```
  std::cout << "std::to_string: " << std::to_string(c) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Instead of calling it "boost new library", why not specify a version number?

Comment: yeah, I tested with 1.49, it prints 8

Comment: 1.49 is hardly "new" (Feb 2012)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old boost version is incorrect.

The result of `lexical_cast` is supposed to be the same as streaming to an ostream. So the result of

```
std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x)
```

is identical to

```
std::cout << x
```

In case of `unsigned char` that means interpreting x as an ASCII code, for other integer types it will give the same result as `itoa`. This is because the `char` types are not considered as arithmetic integers by ostream (see §27.3.6.2 vs §27.3.6.4). The advantage of this approach is that you can output a string by outputting its single chars. If you want the actual numeric value, you can always cast the char to an arithmetic type for output.

[`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) on the other hand works like `itoa` for all integer datatypes, as it does not have an overload for `unsigned char`. The rationale here is that by calling `to_string` you already expressed your intent to perform a conversion, i.e. you are not interested in the character-type quality of the value (which would be the default) but the arithmetic-type quality.

Answer (score 8):

`std::to_string` only provides overloads for numeric types, probably resolving to the `unsigned` version in this case. `lexical_cast`, OTOH, relies on `std::ostream::operator<<` to perform the conversion, thus treating `c` as a character.

Comment: Yes, it took me a while to figure out that `std::to_string` has nothing to do with `boost::to_string` or `boost::lexical_cast`.

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct. `to_string` does not care that `c` is of type `char`, it will read the number in it and cast it into string.

On the other hand, `lexical_cast<std::string>` seems to interpret variables of type `char` as an ascii value. 56 is the ascii value of 8.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of interpretation. If you interpret a `char` as a small integer you print its code in the current character set; this is what `to_string` appears to be doing.

If you interpret it as a character to be printed you issue the corresponding character, i.e. `8` as `boost::lexical_cast` does.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't char to string, it is "unsigned char" to string. And they are both correct. lexical_cast converts using a stringstream instance while std::to_string is overloaded for unsigned which means unsigned char is promoted to unsigned int.